# Lock orientation of Android confirm credentials screen using KeyGaurdManager

Tags: java, android, android-activity, screen-orientation

I am using Device PIN/Pattern/Password screen to login into Android application.

Issue: Application only supports `portrait` mode. But when I start Device login screen using [KeyGautdManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)), System activity opens in `landscape` mode.

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = getKeyGuardManager(v.getContext());
Intent confirmDeviceCredentialIntent = keyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(getString(R.string.DLAScreenTitle), getString(R.string.dlaMsgOnSignIn));
startActivityForResult(confirmDeviceCredentialIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

I want to fix orientation of Activity opened by Android System.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As long as the activity that is being opened is not yours, you cannot control the orientation of it.

There isn't any API to specify orientation mode for an Intent that is being launched.